# How can I automatically populate a separate Excel spreadsheet with information entered into an Excel form

Tags: excel, forms

I have created a "form" within a workbook and I want the data entered in the form fields (cells) to populate a spreadsheet that has column headings with the titled fields of the form.

I have looked at v-look up functions, using vb code, etc., but am still not clear how to best accomplish this.

Ideally, what I would want is for 
A) employees to fill out the form (Sheet 1 of workbook)
B) have the input data populate the spreadsheet (currently Sheet 2 of workbook) adding/creating a new row entry each time the form is submitted
C) Click "submit" button, which will then e-mail the form to those who need to  receive it.  (which I've already created)

Thanks in advance for any input / assistance!

Comment: VBA seems like the natural choice to me. Have you tried coding this at all?

Comment: It appears to be the most probably / easy solution to me as well.  I'm at it again this morning working to see if I can get the code to work correctly.  I've found some examples online, but to be honest, I'm not fluent in VB and know just enough to frustrate myself when I can't get it to work properly.

Comment: If you have some code, post it here. Let us know what isn't working and you're bound to get some help. I have done similar things and will check back a few times today.